# How to make the camera follow the plane in my blender game?

Tags: game-engine, camera

I made a basic plane model and parented the camera to it, but when i fly the plane, the camera follows its location but rotates by itself...[image: This is the set up I have]

Here is a link to download the game: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sic9fc3ne5wkqza/AIRSPACE.blend?dl=0
EDIT: blend exchange wasn't working so I have to use Dropbox

Answer (score 0):

Use camera actuator instead of parenting it.

[image]

Change height, axis, damping, etc to meet your requeriments.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the scale dimensions are not set to 1.
Whenever you change a mesh, those dimensions change as well. You will always have to press CTRL + A and set SCALE to be all right.
Select the airplane, press CTRL+A and SCALE.